# Rewriting URLs in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I am working with a modified Wordpress site URL that looks like this:
http://test3.ober.com/detail-page/?refid=ahla-clinical-research-practice-guide

I want to change the URLs to look like this:
http://test3.ober.com/detail-page/ahla-clinical-research-practice-guide

What Rewrite Rule should I add to the .htaccess file?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Added info: This Wordpress site is using a PHP code widget where we are pulling in content from other MySQL db tables that are not normally part of Wordpress.

```
  if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['refid'])) {

$refid = $wp_query->query_vars['refid'];

$safe_id = mysql_real_escape_string( $refid);
$SQL = "select publication_title, publication_content, publication_date from publications where publication_url_name =  '$safe_id'" ;
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $detail_data = $db_field['publication_content'];
    $title =  $db_field['publication_title'];
    $date = $db_field['publication_date'];
}
mysql_close($db_handle);

$pub_date = date("F d, Y",strtotime($date));
echo "<h1>" . $title  . "</h1>";
echo "<span class=\"date\">" . $pub_date . "</span>";  
echo $detail_data;
}
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)refid=([^&]+)(?:$|&)
RewriteRule ^detail-page/$ detail-page/%1?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Where this comes from `?refid=ahla-clinical-research-practice-guide`?

Comment: @RahilWazir I added more info to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a built- in URL rewrite functionality.  In the WP lingo, these are called "permalinks".  You are likely looking for the "post name" option.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks